# Is it possible to add an ETH node to an existing ARM device that already works as an IPFS node and a Tor Relay?

Tags: ipfs, raspberry-pi, tutorials, tor

I have a RPi4 dedicated to be a IPFS node and a Tor Middle Relay.

Could this same device be used as a Ethereum node as well, without messing up with the others (IPFS and Tor)?

I've seen [this article](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/run-node-raspberry-pi/) on how to make a ARM into a node, but in my case I don't want to have a dedicated Ethereum node.

This device has a 2TB SSD and IPFS doesn't use it almost nothing of it. I could dedicate let's say 1,9TB to Ethereum.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible, I don't see any issues with this setup and a quick check in the respective client github repos (issues) doesn't reveal anything of concern either.